# Can't Issue Any ADB Commands – Says Device Is Offline

Tags: android, macos, adb

I wanna try the new screen record feature in KitKat without rooting my Moto G. I have downloaded only the ADB and Fastboot Unix executables (instead of the whole Android SDK), and I also don't need the drivers because I use a Mac, and I've enabled USB Debugging in Developer Settings. But my Moto G appears as "Offline" in the list of devices when I type "./adb devices" and I can't issue any other ADB commands, such as the screen record command. Help?

Comment: Maybe the Mac version differs from a general Unix one? Try downloading for Mac.

Comment: Have you checked the Rules file? I am not sure if that is applicable for Mac. I just checked the rules file is not applicable for Mac. However you should check if your app is debug-able in the Manifest.